# Are all the values on the Stack smaller than a passed value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stack

I am in the middle of completing a Stack program and am unsure how to formulate a method that determines if all the values on the Stack are smaller than the passed value.

So, for example, for a stack containing top- (1) (1) (2) (3) (5) (5) (2), allSmallerThan( 3 ) should return false because there values on the Stack bigger than 3. On the other hand, for a stack containing top- (1) (1) (2) (3) (5) (5) (2), allSmallerThan( 12 ) should return true because all the values on the stack are less than 12.

I have made the operation signature

```
int Stack<Object>::allSmallerThan( const Object & data ) const;
```

But after that, I am a bit stumped of where to go

Below is the full implementation file. Most of the file was given to us and we have been asked to complete certain operations. This one in particular is killlling

```
#ifndef STACK_CPP
#define STACK_CPP

#include "Stack.h"

namespace cs20 {

template <class Object>
Stack<Object>::Stack() {
    topNode = NULL;
}

template <class Object>
Stack<Object>::Stack( const Stack<Object>& rhs ) {
    topNode = NULL;
    *this = rhs;
}

template <class Object>
Stack<Object>::~Stack() {
    makeEmpty();
    delete topNode;
}

template <class Object>
bool Stack<Object>::isEmpty() const {
    return( (topNode == NULL) );
}

template <class Object>
void Stack<Object>::makeEmpty() {
    while (!isEmpty()) {
        pop();
    }
}
template <class Object>
    int Stack<Object>::allSmallerThan( const Object & data ) const{


    }


template <class Object>
void Stack<Object>::push( const Object& data ) {
    StackNode<Object>* newNode = new StackNode<Object>( data, topNode );
    topNode = newNode;
}

template <class Object>
void Stack<Object>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyStack();
    }
    StackNode<Object> *oldTop = topNode;
    topNode = topNode->getNext();
    delete oldTop;
}

template <class Object>
const Object& Stack<Object>::top( ) const {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyStack();
    }
    StackNode<Object> node = *topNode;
    return( node.getElement() );
}

template <class Object>
Object Stack<Object>::topAndPop( ) {
    Object o = top();
    pop();
    return( o );
}

// Deep copy of linked Stack
template <class Object>
const Stack<Object>& Stack<Object>::operator =( const Stack<Object>& rhs ) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        makeEmpty();
        if (!(rhs.isEmpty())) {
            StackNode<Object> * rhsTopNode = rhs.topNode;
            StackNode<Object> * myTopNode = new StackNode<Object>( rhsTopNode->getElement() );
            topNode = myTopNode;

            rhsTopNode = rhsTopNode->getNext();
            while (rhsTopNode != NULL) {
                myTopNode->setNext( new StackNode<Object>( rhsTopNode->getElement() ) );
                myTopNode = myTopNode->getNext();
                rhsTopNode = rhsTopNode->getNext();
            }
        }
    }
    return( *this );
}

template <class Object> 
std::ostream& Stack<Object>::printStack( std::ostream& outs ) const {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        outs << "Empty Stack";
    }
    else {
        outs << "TOP: ";
        StackNode<Object> * node = topNode;
        while (node != NULL) {
            outs << node->getElement();
            outs << "\n     ";           /// for visual alignment
            node = node->getNext();
        }
    }
    return( outs );
}

}

#endif
```

All the best
Thanks!

Comment: If you implement an `iterator`, you may use generic `algorithm` as, in c++11, `std::all_of`.

Comment: [OT] It seems from the guards that you code the template in `.cpp`. I'm not sure it is what you want, you may prefer in `*.inl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working

```
   template <class Object>
    int Stack<Object>::allSmallerThan( const Object & data ) const{
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw EmptyStack();
        }
        else {
            StackNode<Object> * node = topNode;
            while (node != NULL) {
                if (data <= node->getElement()) //You need to do the comparison by hand
                    return (false);
                node = node->getNext();
            }
        }
        return( true );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As your elements aren't sorted on the stack you have to traverse them manually like in `printStack(...)` and check the values yourself.

You can abort on the first occurence that isn't smaller than the given value.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over all values of the stack. If one of the values is not smaller than the argument, return false. If the loop ends, then all values are smaller so return true.

Comment: What would something like this loop like. I always step over my own feet when doing loops at this point.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
 template <class Object>
        int Stack<Object>::allSmallerThan( const Object & data ) const{
        if (isEmpty()) {
            outs << "Empty Stack";
        }
        else {
            StackNode<Object> * node = topNode;
            while (node != NULL) {
                 if (node >= data) //You need to do the comparison by hand
                  return (false);
                node = node->getNext();
            }
        }
        return( true );
     }
```

Comment: you are comparing an Object with a StackNode<Object> wich will fail most likely. you can access the corresponding Object from node with node->getElement(), but you don't know if there has been implemented a comparison operator...

Comment: you're mixing 14 lines of c++ code with one line of pseudo code, this could lead the OP in the wrong direction. also you use the variable outs wich was not defined before...

Comment: I tried to implement this psuedo code. In the Driver file, what would I pass through ( const Object & data ) ? For example

  case ALLSMALLERTHAN:
                if (stack.allSmallerThan(XXX)) {
                    cout << "all are smaller" << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "all are not smaller" << endl;
                }
                break;

Comment: You must had instancied your stask object with something like this: Stack<type> stack;
So you need to pass an object of the same type: stack.allSmallerThan(type);

Comment: on `if (node >= data)` I am getting the error `Comparison between pointer and integer ('StackNode<int> *' and 'int')`

Comment: It's the pseudo code part,  You getting this error because node is of type StackNode<int>* and data is of type int, so you need to get the Object from StackNode: so something like this: if (node->getObject() >= data)   
as xmoex described